# Node.JS error, TTY.onread

Tags: node.js

I have installed node.js,  I can run node -v and it returns 6.11.0.
But any code that needs an input crashes, "yo doctor" for example and this simple code example also crashes.

Saved as test.js

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

run this as
   node test.js

Just returns the following:

```
What do you think of Node.js? events.js:160

  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: read EINVAL
   at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
   at TTY.onread (net.js:568:26)
```

Similar errors thrown with any node software prompting for input.

Comment: throw in a try, catch so you can actually see the error.

Comment: Also the code works perfectly fine when executed with node 7.8

Comment: Code runs fine on 6.0.0 .

Comment: By the way are you running on windows 10 ? https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1961 may be this can help.

Comment: Running on windows 7.

Comment: Not sure how try/catching it will help, its already showing a stacktrace, not being that nodey, what did you have in mind when its caught ?

Comment: Tried node 7.8.0 and it throws the same error